# Spotlight query to search for all archives and ISO files that their names do not end in bin

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight

The following Spotlight query, correctly returns all archive and ISO files on my system:

```
kind:iso OR kind:archive
```

However, Spotlight treats `.bin` files as archives too and returns `.bin` files in the results as well.

How can I modify the above query and exclude files that end in `bin` from the result? I tried the following query but it is not working:

```
(kind:iso OR kind:archive) AND NOT name:*bin
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution in an IRC channel. Instead of writing `name:*bin` you should use `name:.bin` so the whole query would be:

```
(kind:iso OR kind:archive) AND NOT name:.bin
```